# Loop through table without checking if end of table has been reached

Tags: loops, runtime, pseudocode, sentinel

I really don't like asking a question regarding homework, but this question has me stumped. It seems like the answer should be so simple, yet the answer escapes me!

The question comes from "Data Structures and Algorithms" by Harry Lewis and Larry Denenberg, question 1 of chapter 1. We have a simple for loop for sequential search.

```
function SequentialSearch(table T[0...n-1], key K): integer
{Return position of K in table T, if it is present, otherwise -1}
    for i from 0 to n - 1 do
        if T[i] = K then return i
    return -1
```

Simple enough, right? Okay, for every iteration through this loop, there are two checks: (1) check if T[i] = K, and (2) check if i > n - 1. The runtime for each loop iteration is a constant 2. The question is this: how can the runtime be reduced to 1? How can I get rid of having to check if i > n - 1 (i.e., if the end of the table has been reached)?

The hint given to us is that a sentinel value can be used. Well, that's simple enough, except for one problem, which is this: How does checking against a sentinel value improve the runtime from checking against the table's length? Wouldn't the runtime still be 2 for each iteration regardless of whether I check against the table's length or against a sentinel value?

I'm not expecting to be given an answer here. (The answer will be written in pseudocode.) I'm just stumped at how to implement this to reduce the runtime. To me, it seems like it's reduced to as little as possible, but what do I know?

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so suppose you use a while loop such as "int i = 0; while (T[i] != T[n]) { if (T[++i] = key, return i }". Does that improve the runtime? It seems to me like it shouldn't since there's still 2 checks per iteration.

Answer (score 1):

How about a hint: The sentinel value, which you put into T[n], doesn't have to be the same for every run of the algorithm. It can depend K, the value you're searching for. Does this help?